Unable to Identify Object Coming Out of Basement Floor
Please help me identify this thing in the basement. House built in 1936. Thing is of concrete, attached to the floor, and tapers up and out, starting as a ~6" square and becoming a 10" square at about 5" above the floor. It has many holes in the bottom. It is pictured with water that I just poured in, which may be very slowly going down, though it's hard to tell. There is a floor drain a foot to its right that goes down about a foot and appears to open to an area holding water. The washer and dryer are hooked up nearby. Thinking it may be linked to a sewer gas issue. Let me know if there is anything I can clarify or add.




What picture?  you mention one.

Added two now. Sorry.

The open drain would be the first suspect for sewer gas - put a test plug in it and see if the stench abates. Never see this small, low, variant, but some sort of "not a laundry sink" laundry drain would be my best guess - but just a guess. You can probably plug it with a sheet of plastic over the "bottom with many small holes" and water on top of the plastic if the stench remains after you plug the dubious floor drain.

Since you poured water into it before the picture which confuses this point, is the bottom of the square thing at, above, or below floor level?  i.e. if well below floor level it might be a small sump.

Added a picture of the bottom. The bottom is at, or maybe slightly above, floor level. Certainly not below.
